# How can I fix the frontend registration using angular js and login

Tags: jquery, node.js, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS web app. I need help with routing. I am trying to navigate to index.html if the register is successful(login.html).
There are lots of examples about it but I could not get them to work with my web application. I tried [this], but it's still working.

I have 2 HTML pages; index.html and login.html. Also 2 separate controller files; config.js and login.js

bellow my config.js

```
.run( function ($rootScope,$state, $location, $cookies, $http) {
    $rootScope.version = 20200530;  
    $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });

}) 

.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$httpProvider,$compileProvider){          

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|javascript):/);
     
    
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
     
    
    $stateProvider
      
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })  
        .state('announcement', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/announcement.html'
        })  
        .state('health_tips', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/health_tips.html'
        })     
      
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
        })  

        .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
        }) 
    }
)
```

my login.js

```
contactTracing

.controller('LoginController',['$location', 'AuthenticationService','FlashService',
function($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService){
    var vm = this;

    vm.login = login;

    (function initController() {
        // reset login status
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    })();

    function login() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
            console.log(response == response.data)
            if (response.success == true) {
                FlashService.Success('login successful', true);  
                $location.path('/',false);
            } else {
                FlashService.Error(response.message);
                vm.dataLoading = false;
                alert(response == false)

            }
        });
    };
```

}])

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="contactTracing" data-ng-controller="contactTracingCtrl as mactrl">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Contact Tracing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
<base href="/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
<data ui-view></data>
<script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendors/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-services/authentication.service.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-services/flash.service.js"></script>

 <script src="js/app-services/user.service.js"></script>

<script src="js/controller/user_information.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/health_tips.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/announcement.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/home.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/login.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/register.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': 
    form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form- 
     control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && 
    form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is 
    required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': 
     form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" 
        class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && 
        form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is 
        required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || 
        vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    
        <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
        <a href="/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi there! I suggest you tag the question as AngularJS rather than just Angular, you're more likely to get more experts combing through those who'll be able to help!

Comment: @mad-bunny Your link is not formatted properly so I cannot view your referenced page. Also, did you intentionally truncate your index.html? It is missing the closing body and html tags. Same for login html, it is missing a closing div. I highly recommend making a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) of what you have so far which will make it much easier for us to jump in and debug. Lastly, index.html should be the root page of your angular application and should always be the first page hit for an external request, any further navigation should be virtual navigation to other pages (not a postback).